# C# Constructor declaration

Tags: c#, constructor

Since I am new to the constructor topic, I have a small confusion of why we are using it? Is there any difference between declaring a constructor and not declaring it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29

Comment: [Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ace5hbzh.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Constructor is used to initialize the class object. If you don't declare/define it, then a default constructor would be created for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't declare any constructor, the compiler will generate the default constructor with no parameter.

Consider this class :

```
public Class X
{
    public int A { get; set; }
}
```

No constructor declaration in there, so the compiler will put default constructor in that class like this :

```
public Class X
{
    public int A { get; set; }

    public X () 
    { 
    }

}
```

If you declare constructor in your class, the default constructor will not be generated.

```
public Class X
{
    public int A { get; set; }

    public X (int a) 
    { 
          // do something
    }

}
```

In this sample, the default empty constructor will not be generated.
If you try to create an instance like this :

```
X obj = new X();
```

It will generate compilation error.

More detail : [Default constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608%28v=vs.71%29.aspx%20constructor),
[Constructor in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html)

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference between declaring a public parameterless constructor which simply calls the base class's public parameterless constructor:

```
public class Test
{
    public Test() : base() {}
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
public class Test
{
}
```

The compiler supplies a *default constructor* for you.

(And the `base()` part is implicit; if you don't explicitly chain to another constructor, the compiler will treat it as if you'd tried to chain to the parameterless base class constructor<sup>1</sup>.)

But that doesn't mean that constructors are useless... you would usually put code in there. Typically it copies parameters:

```
public class Test
{
    private readonly string name;

    public Test(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

... but constructors can mostly contain the same code as normal methods. It's worth being aware that while your constructor is running, the object may not be *fully* initialized though, as the constructor bodies for derived classes won't have executed yet. It's advisable not to call virtual methods within a constructor for this reason.

See section 10.11 of the C# 5 spec for details of instance constructors in general, and section 10.11.4 for details of default constructors.

---

<sup>1</sup> More specifically, it will chain as if you'd written `base()`. If there's no parameterless constructor, but there *is* a constructor whose parameters are all optional, that will be called.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are used for many thing for a class.

1. If you want to do something on initialization of instance of class.

   ```
    public class MyClass
    {
        private string myWork = string.Empty;
        public MyClass()
        {
            myWork = "Started";
        }
     }
   ```
2. If you want to limitize the scope for object creation of class

   ```
   public class MyClass
   {
       private string myWork = string.Empty;
       protected MyClass() 
       {
           myWork = "Started";
       }
   }
   ```

There are many other things like base class support and others. Please search on MSDN also.